# Having trouble in populating my html dropdown with csv file of single row location using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, csv, dropdown

I was trying to populate me html dropdown with a csv file containing a single row of locations using JavaScript but it isn't working. Can someone help what is the issue here? The locations.csv file is in the same folder as this index.html file.

I have removed unnecessary part of the code so if you find any syntax error, please ignore. The code is running fine, the only issue is the location is not getting repopulated.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('prediction-form');
const resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');
const locationSelect = document.getElementById('location');

// Fetch locations from CSV file
fetch('locations.csv')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(csvData => {
    const rows = csvData.split('\n');
    for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
      const location = rows[i].trim();
      if (location !== '') {
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = location;
        option.textContent = location;
        locationSelect.appendChild(option);
      }
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error fetching locations:', error);
  });

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Retrieve the form values
  const location = document.getElementById('location').value;
  const sqft = parseFloat(document.getElementById('sqft').value);
  const bath = parseFloat(document.getElementById('bath').value);
  const bhk = parseFloat(document.getElementById('bhk').value);
});
```

```html
<h1>House Price Prediction</h1>
<form id="prediction-form">
  <label for="location">Location:</label>
  <select id="location" name="location" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select location</option>
  </select>

  <label for="sqft">Total Square Footage:</label>
  <input type="number" id="sqft" name="sqft" required>

  <label for="bath">Number of Bathrooms:</label>
  <input type="number" id="bath" name="bath" required>

  <label for="bhk">Number of Bedrooms:</label>
  <input type="number" id="bhk" name="bhk" required>

  <button type="submit">Predict Price</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

The code isn't populating the html dropdown for locations as expected. Help!

Comment: There's *a lot* of reasons this may not be working. I would suggest you start debugging it by opening the console and checking what the error is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the `fetch("location.csv")` and replace it with a `locations` variable you can see that your logic is working, so the problem is with your `fetch()` or your data. If it's an issue with your `fetch()` you should see some error in the console. Most likely something like a HTTP status code 400 Not Found, but that's a guess. In that case you should check whether the file is really present on the server on the required location/ path and adjust the path accordingly.

If it's an error with your data e.g. the file does not actually contain any locations or does not contain a `\n` then you won't see any locations, because you also have a small bug: your `for` loop starts at index `1`, not `0` so the first location would not be displayed. Unless of course the first line is a heading, in that case that's all good.

Here your code with the `fetch()` removed and an variable `csvData` which emulates a `.csv` files as you are expecting it.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('prediction-form');
const resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');
const locationSelect = document.getElementById('location');

// Fetch locations from CSV file
const csvData = "Locations\nLoc1\nLoc2\nLoc3"
const rows = csvData.split('\n');
for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
  const location = rows[i].trim();
  if (location !== '') {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = location;
    option.textContent = location;
    locationSelect.appendChild(option);
  }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Retrieve the form values
  const location = document.getElementById('location').value;
  const sqft = parseFloat(document.getElementById('sqft').value);
  const bath = parseFloat(document.getElementById('bath').value);
  const bhk = parseFloat(document.getElementById('bhk').value);
});
```

```html
<h1>House Price Prediction</h1>
<form id="prediction-form">
  <label for="location">Location:</label>
  <select id="location" name="location" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select location</option>
  </select>

  <label for="sqft">Total Square Footage:</label>
  <input type="number" id="sqft" name="sqft" required>

  <label for="bath">Number of Bathrooms:</label>
  <input type="number" id="bath" name="bath" required>

  <label for="bhk">Number of Bedrooms:</label>
  <input type="number" id="bhk" name="bhk" required>

  <button type="submit">Predict Price</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```